# Failed to register Instance in AutoFac?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofac

I want to use the existing mock instance of my project in AutoFac. I do not want to rewrite my PROD code. So I found something AutoFac which is not working. I think I am missing something.

I have tried below code.

```
public AboutTideEditorMockTest () {
    aboutTideService = new AboutTideEditorService (iAboutTideEditorRepository.Object, exceptionLogServiceMock.Object);
    aboutTideServiceWithNullParam = new AboutTideEditorService (null, exceptionLogServiceMock.Object);
}

//This is my test case
[FactWithAutomaticDisplayName]
public void Test1 () {
    var cb = new ContainerBuilder ();
    var studyLoaderMock = new Mock<IAboutTideEditorService> ().Object;
    var studyLoaderMock1 = iAboutTideEditorRepository.Object;
    var studyLoaderMock2 = exceptionLogServiceMock.Object;
    cb.RegisterInstance (studyLoaderMock).As<IAboutTideEditorService> ();
    cb.RegisterInstance (studyLoaderMock1).As<IAboutTideEditorRepository> ();
    cb.RegisterInstance (studyLoaderMock2).As<IExceptionLogService> ();
    var container = cb.Build ();
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope ()) {
        var component = scope.Resolve<AboutTideEditorService> ();
        responseData = component.AddAboutTideContent (applicationUser, aboutTide);
        Assert.Equal (ProcessStatusEnum.Invalid, responseData.Status);
    }
}
```

I want to use the existing mock instance that I am passing to "RegisterInstance".  When I am trying to debug my test case I am getting "responseData" null. I am not able to go inside in AddAboutTideContent.

Comment: I know this isn't what you want to hear - but unit tests that interact with Autofac are a bad idea. You should write your code in such a way that they aren't using Autofac as Service Locator pattern (and so your tests won't need to interact with Autofac). If you'd like more specific advice, we'll need to see a [mcve] that we can repro at our end.

Comment: Is this basically the same thing you asked for in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702794/how-to-automock-for-existing-mock-object)?

Comment: You appear to be registering your instance as the interface `IAboutTideEditorService`, but are trying to resolve `AboutTideEditorService`. You need to resolve the same type as was registered.

Comment: Yeah in my previous question I was not knowing what we can use after reading on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061812/using-autofac-with-moq this link i tried this solution. but still it didnt work for me :(

Comment: @Iridium I tried that too but why it was not going inside the service after pressing f11. It is coming out of it and giving responseData null.

Comment: Why do you need `var component = scope.Resolve<AboutTideEditorService>();`? Why not use `var component = studyLoadMock;`?

Comment: Why is `aboutTideService` instantiated and then not used?

Comment: Currently i am using aboutTideService instantiate only in my project but mocking each interface of service is very irrtating. Everytime i need to look out which interface has not nock when test case get failed. Thats why i decided for AutoFac but i cant change my Prod code

Comment: @mjwills do u get my query?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting up the mock return value and you need to resolve `IAboutTideEditorService` rather than `AboutTideEditorService`.

You also need to generate the mocks differently. There is no need to change the production code though!

Do it like this:

```
[FactWithAutomaticDisplayName]
public void Test1() {
  var cb = new ContainerBuilder();

  var studyLoaderMock = new Mock<IAboutTideEditorService>();
  var studyLoaderMock1 = new Mock<IAboutTideEditorRepository>(); // you don't need that when resolving only IAboutTideEditorService
  var studyLoaderMock2 = new Mock<IExceptionLogService>(); // you don't need that when resolving only IAboutTideEditorService

  cb.RegisterInstance(studyLoaderMock.Object).As<IAboutTideEditorService>();
  cb.RegisterInstance(studyLoaderMock1.Object).As<IAboutTideEditorRepository>(); // you don't need that when resolving only IAboutTideEditorService
  cb.RegisterInstance(studyLoaderMock2.Object).As<IExceptionLogService>(); // you don't need that when resolving only IAboutTideEditorService

  var container = cb.Build();

  studyLoaderMock
    .Setup(x => x.AddAboutTideContent(It.IsAny<YourTypeHereForParameterA>,
                                      It.IsAny<YourTypeHereForParameterB>)
             .Returns(new MyResponseDataType()); // add the right types here necessary, I can't tell which types they are because I am not seeing the functions code

  using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
    var component = scope.Resolve<IAboutTideEditorService>(); // changed to IAboutTideEditorService
    responseData = component.AddAboutTideContent(applicationUser, aboutTide);
    Assert.Equal(ProcessStatusEnum.Invalid, responseData.Status);
  }
}
```

Your function call was returning `null` because that's the default behavior of a mock with `Moq` = `MockBehavior.Loose`. If you want a function of a mock to return a specific value for non explicit or explicit parameters, you have to call `Setup(delegate)` and `Returns(objectInstance)` or `Returns(Func<ObjectType>)`.

In general your test-setup doesn't make much sense. You are basically only registering mocks with the Autofac-Container which makes the container itself irrelevant for your tests. Using `IoC` for tests is usually only required when you are directly testing against the implementations rather than mocks. Those tests are called `Integration-Tests`.

It would make more sense like this:

```
[FactWithAutomaticDisplayName]
public void Test1() {
  var cb = new ContainerBuilder();

  var studyLoaderMock1 = new Mock<IAboutTideEditorRepository>();that when resolving only IAboutTideEditorService
  var studyLoaderMock2 = new Mock<IExceptionLogService>();
  var studyLoader = new AboutTideEditorService(studyLoaderMock1.Object, studyLoaderMock2.Object);

  cb.RegisterInstance(studyLoader).As<IAboutTideEditorService>();

  var container = cb.Build();

  // now setup the functions of studyLoaderMock1 and studyLoaderMock2 
  // required for your function `AddAboutTideContent` from `IAboutTideEditorService` to work.

  using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
    var component = scope.Resolve<IAboutTideEditorService>(); // changed to IAboutTideEditorService
    responseData = component.AddAboutTideContent(applicationUser, aboutTide);
    Assert.Equal(ProcessStatusEnum.Invalid, responseData.Status);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that I am assuming here the order of the parameters required for `AboutTideEditorService`. For more information on how to setup mocks with `Moq` take a look [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).